# I need a tool for my Google Chrome to prevent closing several Tabs at once

Tags: chrome

I am using Chrome Version 39.0.2171.95.

Chrome never warns whenever I close my Chrome browser when there are several Tabs opened. I have tried Window Close Protector 2.2 but it does not work at all.

So I need another tool or extension to help me out -- does one exist?

Comment: If you want to try to influence on existence of this feature, vote it up on issue tracker of google developers:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=147

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google had an extension to do that called [Chrome Toolbox](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-toolbox-by-google/fjccknnhdnkbanjilpjddjhmkghmachn), but it has been discontinued.

Apparently, this currently can't be done according to [this post](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/XJE1LBY76g8%5B1-25%5D) from a Google employee. Quote:

> Thank you all for your feedback. At this time, we don't have plans to implement this feature. Part of Chrome's design philosophy is to avoid interrupting you with annoying questions that only sometimes matter. Still, we do see how accidental closing of tabs can be frustrating, and we are thinking of a better solution. [...]

<sup>(The remainder of the post suggests the above obsolete extension and some workarounds on Mac)</sup>

However, there is another workaround posted by a Google user on [this post](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/XJE1LBY76g8%5B301-325%5D). That is basically to open a website that asks for confirmation before closing, and leave that page open or pinned.

[Here is the example website](http://www.maki-chan.de/preventclose.htm). I've tested it, and it works for me.

---

Note that [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) has that feature by default. It may be worth switching if you use it much

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at this programme I created just for this purpose.  It is an external application that will disable the X(Close) button for chosen applications so that you cannot X-Log chrome. (you can still exit by using the top-left menu)

https://sourceforge.net/projects/xlogprotection/files/?source=navbar